# Where are the Expression-based Labeling options in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have imported a layer into my map to show the location of towns/cities. However I had to set graduated styling so that only cities over a certain population show.

I now want to label the ones that show but if I add labels all of the labels show rather than just the ones which I want to appear in my map.

I think I can solve the problem using Expression-based labeling. Following this tutorial: https://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/expression-based-labeling-for-qgis/

But I can't find the settings. When I go into the labelling options I see this:

[image: Label options]

What do I do next? Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the little `...` icon :)

*Maybe I should rename it to "expression..."*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and on the IRC as well. I would say that it is not all that obvious to a new user. A change of labelling might be helpful.